# What happens when I accept a pull/merge request which is behind master?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, pull-request

I'm reviewing pull requests/merge requests using GitLab's web UI. Usually I accept them via this web UI but from time to time I've seen stuff from other merge requests went missing when I didn't rebase master onto the branch before accepting it.

So can you tell me what happens when I accept a pull request/merge request which is behind the current master (see screenshot)

It is from GitLab but should also apply to GitHub.

[image]

Comment: If there are no conflicts it will merge your changes to master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

- No conflict. It's good to you.
- Has conflict. You will use IDE or text editor for resolving conflict sections.

You can see these information on Web GUI (before decision).

No need to worry. Press button `Accept Merge request`, you still can revert or rollback.